# Azure Synapse Serverless query wildcard performance

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to query parquet files from my abfss v2 container.  That data is structured like this:

```
daily/pricedate=2018-04-01/part-0.parquet
...
daily/pricedate=2022-11-16/part-0.parquet
```

If I do this query (note the `result.filepath(1)` in the `select` and the wildcard in the `BULK`:

```
SELECT top 10 cast(convert(datetime,result.filepath(1), 120) as date) as pricedate, col1, col2

FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'daily/pricedate=*/*.parquet',
        DATA_SOURCE='adls',
        FORMAT = 'parquet'
    ) 
    with (
    pricedate date,
    col1 float,
    col2 float)
    as [result] 

    where result.filepath(1)='2022-10-31'
GO
```

then it takes 10-15 seconds

if I take out the wildcard and the `where` like this:

```
SELECT top 10 cast(convert(datetime,'2022-10-31',120) as date) as pricedate, col1, col2

FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'daily/pricedate=2022-10-31/*.parquet',
        DATA_SOURCE='adls',
        FORMAT = 'parquet'
    ) 
    with (
    pricedate date,
    col1 float,
    col2 float)
    as [result] 

    --where result.filepath(1)='2022-10-31'
GO
```

then it takes 0-2 seconds.

In both cases, under messages in MSQLMS, it says `Total size of data scanned is 3 megabytes, total size of data moved is 1 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes.`

I tried wrapping the `result.filepath(1)` with a `collate` like this: `(result.filepath(1) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8)` but that's the same performance.

How can I get it the performance of each of these to be, if not the same, better than 5x different.

Comment: We use this pattern extensively, particularly in Views, but I have not noticed a performance gap like this. Unrelated, but you should not need to reference pricedate in the with clause.

Comment: Yeah I tried having it in the with and not, just so happens the one I copy-pasted has it in there.

Comment: How many `pricedate=YYYY-MM-DD` folders do you have? Yeah. If you hardcode it to only scan one folder it’s going to be faster than having it look at all folders but then skipping most folders with the filepath where clause.

Comment: @GregGalloway however many days there are in between those days in the example so I guess 1500 give or take. You think that's it?

Comment: I would consider moving to monthly and daily partitions and see how it performs.

Comment: Do you mean monthly and yearly?

Comment: Yes. I mean `daily/year=2022/month=11/pricedate=2022-11-16/part-0.parquet` and `where result.filepath(1)='2022' and result.filepath(2)='11' and result.filepath(3)='2022-11-16'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249722/discussion-between-dean-macgregor-and-greggalloway).

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though when Synapse sees wildcards in the path that it scans the directory before it looks at the rest of the query.  This directory scan is very time intensive so there's a significant cost in having a lot of partitions.  I took part of @GregGalloway's advice and repartitioned like this:

```
yearmo/year=YYYY/month=MM/part-0.parquet
```

so the number of partitions went from nearly 1700 blobs to about 50.  My file sizes went from about 2MBs to about 100MBs.  I might have used a bigger compression level in the original than I am in the repartition so I'm not reading much into that.

With that my query times went down precipitously.  Unfortunately my query sizes have also gone up precipitously so buyer beware I guess.